# issue on compiling package using opencv

Tags: opencv, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying the HOG based human detection algorithm under ros, and following the source file of opencv/samples/cpp/peopledetect.cpp (This source file can be compiled using g++ without issue on my computer,
g++ -o output peopledetect.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`).

But after putting into an ros package, I can't get the similar codes to compile successfully. I did follow the instructions at [www.ros.org/wiki/opencv2](http://www.ros.org/wiki/opencv2)  to set CMakeLists.txt and manifest.xml. But I still keep getting the following compile error,

---

/home/ros/spyrobot/human_detect/src/human_detect.cpp:27:1: error: ‘hog’ does not name a type
make[2]: * [CMakeFiles/human_detect.dir/src/human_detect.o] Error 1
make[1]: * [CMakeFiles/human_detect.dir/all] Error 2
make:* [all] Error 2

---

The error refers to the following two lines which are copied from the peopledetect.cpp source file,

HOGDescriptor hog;

hog.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector());

My current environment, ubuntu 12.04, ROS fuerte, ros-fuerte-opencv2 2.4.0, ros-fuerte-vision-opencv 1.8.2

thanks for your advice in advance

clark

---

**EDIT**:

The tricky thing is that I can manually compile the sample peopledetect.cpp file (which also use HOGDescriptor) using,
g++ -o test peopledetect.cpp -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc
or simply
g++ -o test peopledetect.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`

but why ROS can't compile the  package with the similar function call?

PS: Some further info on my pc,

pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv

-I/opt/ros/fuerte/include/opencv -I/opt/ros/fuerte/include  -L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab

Any further suggestions are welcome.

---

**EDIT 2:**

My mistake!
I originally wanted to decleare hog as a global variable but put not only its declaration but also the function call

hog.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector())

right after the #include (s)... and it is this silly mistake that caused the compile error.

Anyway, thank Kevin again for the help.

clark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35012/issue-on-compiling-package-using-opencv/) by [clark](https://answers.ros.org/users/401/clark/) on ROS Answers with karma: 393 on 2012-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you are missing an include file that defines hog ... double check CMakeLists.txt and your cpp file

---

**Edit**

```
error: ‘hog’ does not name a type
```

I think the error is with hog not with opencv? The error message makes no mention of opencv errors. Are you including hog's includes and linking correctly to the right libraries?

Also, why are you not using the opencv 2 headers:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

Don't mix and match OpenCV 1 and 2 headers ... you can get errors.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clark](https://answers.ros.org/users/401/clark/) on 2012-05-28**:
I have strictly followed the sample file and included the following header files

## include <opencv/cv.h>

## include <opencv/highgui.h>

## include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

## include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

## include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>

Can't figure out which file I still miss

**Comment by [clark](https://answers.ros.org/users/401/clark/) on 2012-05-28**:
Kevein,
thanks for the advice. The HOGDescriptor definition is inside <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>, and the related lib is -lopencv_objdetect, which is part of opencv2. So the header and library shouldn't be the reason.
I also replaced all opencv 1 headers, but the compile is still the  same